# Coudn't connect to the remote computer error - Visual Studio Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, iis-8, entity-framework-migrations, webdeploy

I'm trying to Publish/Deploy an Asp.net MVC EF Code First application to the server through Web Deploy option using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition IDE.
The server is connected through a VPN connection and is able to be pinged from the publishing ( local) machine.

As per the error message suggestion , Installed Web Deploy 3.6 in the server and the Web Management Services ( WMSVC) is running successfully in the Server with IIS 8.0 . 
Also, made sure that the WMSVC has remote connection enabled . 
Now, doubting whether any Firewall rules may be the culprit but not sure or whether any other issues. 
Tried , checked the  server ports 80 and 8172 which shows as below

```
netstat -aon | findstr :8172
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8172           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:8172              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
netstat -aon | findstr :80
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:80             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

This means Port is disabled? 
Or chances of any other things missing to get this deployment done successfully?
Thanks in advance.

It shows the following error ,
[image: Error Img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by creating a public ip instead of the VPN connection and enabled the ports. Also, site name was prepended site name with "Default Web Site/".